# Error with my SQL in vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

sSQL = "SELECT Stock, Scanned FROM Products&
WHERE ((([Stock])=Forms!Products![StockCode]))                                                
And ((([Scanned])=Forms!Products![Scanned Information]));"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
MsgBox "This is not correct"
Else
MsgBox "wooooo this works"
End If
```

I know my SQL query is wrong but I'm not sure how to structure it correctly and I keep getting errors. Am I suppose to break it up with more inverted commas and leave the `Forms!Products![StockCode]` outside the commas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thought that you need to add it in with inverted commas is correct. This should work for you:

```
sSQL = "SELECT Stock, Scanned FROM Products " & _
        "WHERE  [Stock] = '" & Forms!Products![StockCode] &"' " & _                                              
        "AND    [Scanned] = '" & Forms!Products![Scanned Information] & "';"

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
```

*Note I have removed all your parentheses, they are redundant, `((1)=(1))` means exactly the same as `1=1`*